# String formatting into quoted lines

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a list:

```
l = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']
```

and I need to store it in a variable such that it will print it as:

```
'str1\n'
'str2\n'
'str3\n'
'str4'
```

including the single quote and a `\n`.

Right now I'm doing:

```
input_string = "\'" + l[0] + "\\n\'\n\'" + l[1] + "\\n\'\n\'" + l[2] + "\\n\'\n\'" + l[3] + "\'"
print(input_string)
```

but is there a prettier way by using `str.format()` where we don't need to escape the `'\n'`?

Comment: Why the strange restrictions on not needing to escape the `\n`? You are already escaping the newline sequence. Note that you don't need to escape the `'` single quotes.

Comment: Using r" .. " is there some way to escape it?

Comment: Sure, you can use `r"'{}'\n"`, but your own code could do the same.

Comment: I'm not seeing the reason for three downvotes here.

Comment: Neither do I .. @JimFasarakisHilliard. I tried to be as clear as possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape the newline or use a `r'...'` raw string literal to prevent it being interpreted as an escape sequence. You could use a loop to handle all but the last to add that escaped newline:

```
'\n'.join([r"'{}\n'".format(e) for e in l[:-1]] + ["'{}'".format(l[-1])])
```

Demo:

```
>>> l = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']
>>> '\n'.join([r"'{}\n'".format(e) for e in l[:-1]] + ["'{}'".format(l[-1])])
"'str1\\n'\n'str2\\n'\n'str3\\n'\n'str4'"
>>> print(_)
'str1\n'
'str2\n'
'str3\n'
'str4'
```

I suspect that you really just want to show *Python* strings, so their representations:

```
'\n'.join([repr(e + '\n') for e in l[:-1]] + [repr(l[-1])])
```

For your simplified input this produces the same output as the above expression:

```
>>> '\n'.join([repr(e + '\n') for e in l[:-1]] + [repr(l[-1])])
"'str1\\n'\n'str2\\n'\n'str3\\n'\n'str4'"
>>> print(_)
'str1\n'
'str2\n'
'str3\n'
'str4'
```

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in the question earlier. This is quite helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll could just add a newline character and then make use of `repr` to print:

```
In [703]: for x in [x + '\n' if i != len(l) - 1 else x for i, x in enumerate(l)]:
     ...:     print(repr(x))
     ...:     
'str1\n'
'str2\n'
'str3\n'
'str4'
```

This doesn't involve escaping your newlines (which is what you seem to want), but I would recommend escaping them.

---

Storing to a variable would involve storing `repr` inside the list itself followed by a call to `str.join`:

```
In [708]: string = '\n'.join([repr(x + '\n') if i != len(l) - 1 else repr(x) for i, x in enumerate(l)])

In [709]: print(string)
'str1\n'
'str2\n'
'str3\n'
'str4'
```

Comment: I edited my question to remove the ambiguity that I only needed to print it. I actually want to store this in a variable such that on printing it, the answer results.

Comment: @A.Shenzy Edited my answer. But it's a lot like Martjin Pieters' second answer, so if it helps you, accept his answer.